# scrapy and xpath: get the text in a child element, if the parent element contains text

Tags: xpath, scrapy

How do i get the text of a child element, if the parent element contains text with a specific string?

For example:

```
<li>
    "string1"
    <span>
        "Hello"
    </span>
</li>
<li>
    "string2"
    <span>
        "Ola"
    </span>
</li>
```

From the above html code, how to get only string "Ola" using xpath?

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: //li/text()[contains(.,'string1')]/following::span/text()
I tried few other ways but didnt work out.

Comment: That's because you confuse `following` with `following-sibling`: `//li/text()[contains(.,'string2')]/following-sibling::span/text()`, but actually it should return required string also. Not sure what is your exact issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing scrapy, I would try

```
//li[text()[contains(.,"string2")]]/span/text()
```

- `//li[text()[contains(.,"string2")]]` select a `li` element that text contains `string2`
- `/span` select a element `span` below the selected `li`
- `/text()`: return the text of the selected span element

Update: This is simpler and should also work:

```
//li[contains(text(),"string2")]/span/text()
```